# Why am I not getting a live response to Comet server stream events?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, comet

I have a CGI script that streams events:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
print 'Content-Type: text/event-stream\n'

while (True):
    delay()
    print 'event: item'
    print 'data: ' + get_random_event()
    print ''
```

From the command line, it sends random events at random intervals (every few seconds).

However, I have the following JavaScript:

```
var source = new EventSource('feed.cgi');

source.addEventListener('message', function(current_event)
    {
    alert(current_event.data);
    }, false);
```

This has never got me an alert. There are no errors in the Chrome JavaScript console, but so far I have never gotten a discernible recognition that the code listening to the server script has received an event.

Do you have suggestions for how I can get these?

--EDIT--

I should probably give the first CGI script for completion. FireFox says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://[deleted]/feed.cgi." But I can execute a CGI script normally that's in a sibling directory, and Apache's finest-grained Directory setting is still on a directory that is parent to both and meant to allow scripts with a .cgi extension to run as CGI. And the script is set to mode 0755.

Adding a file flush after an increment of behaviour doesn't seem to alter the script's reception.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import sys
import time

timescale = 5

names = [
    'Adam',
    'Bob',
    'Carol',
    'David',
    'Eddie',
    'Frank',
    'George',
    'Harry',
    'Ike',
    'Jim',
    'Kenny',
    'Larry',
    'Mary',
    'Nancy',
    'Oliver',
    'Peter',
    'Quincy',
    'Roger',
    'Sam',
    'Thomas',
    'Uncle',
    'Vincent',
    'William',
    'Xavier',
    'Yogi',
    'Zachary',
    ]

notifications = [
    'applied for a position at ACME.',
    'went to an interview at ACME.',
    'accepted an offer from ACME.',
    ]

def delay():
    time.sleep((random.random() + random.random()) * timescale)

def get_random_event():
    result = '<div class="activity"><span class="name">'
    result += random.choice(names)
    result += '</span> '
    result += random.choice(notifications)
    result += '</div>'
    return result

print 'Content-Type: text/event-stream\n'

while (True):
    print 'event: item'
    print 'data: ' + get_random_event()
    print ''
    sys.stderr.flush()
    delay()
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from our code and [W3chools Server Sent Event documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) I build an example which runs succesfully in chomium and firefox with these modifications (with lighttpd):

1. add a '\n' at the end of print
2. flush the standard output insteadof the standard error

So the while should be:

```
while (True):
    print 'event: item' + '\n'
    print 'data: ' + get_random_event() + '\n'
    print ''
    sys.stdout.flush()
    delay()
```